# Change content of image interactively using slider widgets

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to change content of an image interactively using a slider (e.g. for applying a median operation with different kernel sizes).

While this works well if I only show one resulting image (cf commented lines), I run into trouble when using the subplot function, since the image will not get updated.

What am I missing?

```
%matplotlib inline
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings

from skimage.morphology import disk
from skimage.filters import rank
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import skimage.data


def f(Median_Size):
    selem = disk(int(Median_Size))
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
        img_median = rank.median(img_gray, selem=selem) 

    ax_neu.imshow(img_median, cmap="gray")
    fig.canvas.draw()
    #plt.imshow(img_median, cmap="gray") #This would work
    #plt.show()

image = skimage.data.camera() #plt.imread("Test.png")       
img_gray = rgb2gray(image)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
ax_orig = fig.add_subplot(121) 
ax_neu = fig.add_subplot(122) 

ax_orig.imshow(img_gray, cmap="gray")
ax_neu.imshow(img_gray, cmap="gray")

interact(f, Median_Size=widgets.IntSlider(min=1,max=21,step=2,value=1))
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Your code works perfectly as far as I can tell (using `plt.imread()` instead of `skimage.data.camera()`). Including the part about subplots. Can you provide more information about the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue 100% using jupyter notebook 4.4.1 with python 2.7 and matplotlib 2.1. @DizietAsahi What versions are you using?

Comment: Interesting. I'm using matplotlib: 2.0.2, jupyter: 4.3.0, python: 3.6.1

Comment: Oh, I should point out that I'm using `%matplotlib notebook` instead of `inline` if that makes a difference (I don't get interactions of any kind when I use `inline`)

Comment: @DizietAsahi Yes that makes a difference. Using `%matplotlib notebook` is indeed one possible solution to this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Using `%matplotlib notebook`

Instead of the inline backend, you may use the notebook backend. This will allow to call `figure.canvas.draw()` as expected from running the code as a script. Replace the line `%matplotlib inline` by

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

and restart the Kernel.

[image]

#### Using `display`

You may `display` the newly changed figure after it has been changed. The drawback is that it creates the output twice. A workaround would then be to put interact in a new cell and capture the output from the first cell.

```
%%capture
%matplotlib inline
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings

from skimage.morphology import disk
from skimage.filters import rank
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import skimage.data


def f(Median_Size):
    selem = disk(int(Median_Size))
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
        img_median = rank.median(img_gray, selem=selem) 

    ax_neu.imshow(img_median, cmap="gray")
    fig.canvas.draw()
    display(fig)

image = skimage.data.camera() #plt.imread("Test.png")       
img_gray = rgb2gray(image)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
ax_orig = fig.add_subplot(121) 
ax_neu = fig.add_subplot(122) 

ax_orig.imshow(img_gray, cmap="gray")
ax_neu.imshow(img_gray, cmap="gray")
```

In a new cell

```
interact(f, Median_Size=widgets.IntSlider(min=1,max=21,step=2,value=1));
```

The output would then look like:
[image]

Comment: One thing I notice running this example (and the original) is that the update can take some time. Adding a title to the filtered subplot in f() makes things clearer: ax_neu.set_title("Median filter size: {}".format(Median_Size))

Comment: I had a similar issue, but with far more elements in my plot (1 image, 1 colormap, one line plot, and 2 text boxes) all controlled by a `FloatSlider` and arranged using `subplot2grid`. The display option worked best for me.

Comment: Also, I had to revert to Jupyter notebook, because in Jupyter Lab only the 1st option works, but then the update time between images makes the interactivity rather pointless, as you do not appreciate the dynamic changes in the image.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48337628/18629819) since I don't have enough reputation, so I'll answer directly.

To extend their answer, you can wrap your method with `@interact` and define the parameter to adjust defining it as a keyword argument in the method definition hence avoiding the need to import widgets.

(Some implementation differences might appear in my code because I've had to modify some lines according to my `ipykernel`, `matplotlib` or `skimage` version)

In a first cell, define your globals:

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings

from skimage.morphology import disk
from skimage.filters import rank
import skimage.data

plt.ioff()    # Had to add this line to avoid the cell showing axes

image = skimage.data.camera() #plt.imread("Test.png")
img_gray = image

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
ax_orig = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax_neu = fig.add_subplot(122)

ax_orig.imshow(img_gray, cmap="grey");
```

Then, in a second one, define your method with the `interact` wrapper and the keyword argument to adjust as `(start, stop, step)`:

```
@interact
def f(Median_Size=(0, 20, 2)):
    selem = disk(int(Median_Size))
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

        # Had to change keyword argument with my version of skimage
        img_median = rank.median(img_gray, footprint=selem)

    ax_neu.imshow(img_median, cmap="gray")
    fig.canvas.draw()
    display(fig)
```

It will result in an output similar to the one shown in [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) answer:

[How to interactlively change image content with a slider wrapping a method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PtKM.png)

(Image is different since there has been a [copyright issue](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3927))

Thanks to [@Avi Chawla](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7143189947401871360?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop) for the technique sharing.